# lxc-create: bad template: download

Tags: 12.04, lxc, container

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. According to the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html), there should be a `-t download` template option for the `lxc-create` command. However I get the following output:

```
sudo lxc-create -t download -n container-name
lxc-create: No such file or directory - bad template: download

lxc-create: bad template: download
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the guide for 14.04 - the link with `lts` links to the guide for the latest LTS version (currently 14.04). The [12.04 guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/lxc.html) uses different arguments for `-t`:

> ```
> sudo lxc-create -t ubuntu -n CN
> ```

Presumably, the `download` template was introduced after 12.04.

Answer (score 14):

Under Ubuntu 14.04+ you can install LXC templates with

```
sudo apt-get install lxc-templates
```

(Unfortunately the templates are not installed by default with `sudo apt-get install lxc`)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about what this command is supposed to do. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: The question is rather specific to 12.04.

Comment: This works for Ubuntu 18.04 and should be correct answer.